# how to request the user to turn on location services

Tags: ios, gps, xamarin, uialertview, cllocationmanager

I need my app to access the user's current location. It checks at the beginning of the app if the user has it set or not. and if not i need the app to show a prompt for it to use location services. Like a an alert view and on lick of the button it should take you to the screen of location services on iphone.

Comment: That's the behaviour by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the for locationServicesEnabled and if the location service is allowed for your application by this code:

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] && [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
    //do your works
} else {
   //show an alert
}
```

Comment: how can i redirect the user on button click though in an alert

Comment: Do you mean: how to redirect to the setting to activate the location service for your application? If this is the case, the answer is: just start your location service if user accept your alert. For the 1st time, iDevice will prompt the user for permission to use it in your application.